# New page in ITextSharp does not create new page

Tags: c#, itext

In the following code I create a pdf dynamically using ITextSharp.
I want the 2nd table to be splitted when there is not room enough on the page.

How can this be accomplished ? I tried it with the newPage method on the pdf stamper, but no new page has been created...

(not all codepaths included for readability)

```
private byte[] DoGenerateStatisticsPerOrganisationalUnitPdf(
        string emptyPdfFile,
        DateTime currentDateTime,
        string organisationalUnit,
        int? roleId,
        DateTime? fromDate,
        DateTime? toDate)
    {
        var pdfReader = new ITextSharp.pdf.PdfReader(emptyPdfFile); // note that PdfReader is not IDisposeable

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (ITextSharp.pdf.PdfStamper pdfStamper = new ITextSharp.pdf.PdfStamper(pdfReader, memoryStream))
        {
            // Get content bytes of first page
            var pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1);

            // Make a page width/height large rectangle column for write actions
            var ct = new ITextSharp.pdf.ColumnText(pdfContentByte);

            ct.SetSimpleColumn(
                PageStartX,
                PageStartY,
                PageEndX,
                PageEndY);

            var paragraph = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(new ITextSharp.Chunk("Statistieken Profchecks", titleFont));
            ct.AddElement(paragraph);

            // Add printed date time
            var dateTimeText = string.Format(
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                "Afdrukdatum: {0}",
                currentDateTime.ToString(DateFormat, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
            paragraph = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(new ITextSharp.Chunk(dateTimeText, rowFont));
            ct.AddElement(paragraph);

            // Add selected filter
            var filterItems = string.Empty;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(organisationalUnit))
            {
                filterItems += "\n" + string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "   ° Organisatie: {0}", organisationalUnit);
            }

            if (roleId.HasValue)
            {
                filterItems += "\n" + string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "   ° Rol: {0}", roleService.GetById(roleId.Value).Name);
            }

            if (fromDate.HasValue)
            {
                filterItems += "\n" + string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "   ° Datum van: {0}", fromDate.Value.ToString(DateFormat, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
            }

            if (toDate.HasValue)
            {
                filterItems += "\n" + string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "   ° Datum t/m: {0}", toDate.Value.ToString(DateFormat, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
            }

            var filterText = string.Format(
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                "Geselecteerde filter: {0}",
                filterItems.Length > 0 ? filterItems : "(geen filter)");
            paragraph = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(new ITextSharp.Chunk(filterText, rowFont));
            ct.AddElement(paragraph);

            paragraph = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(new ITextSharp.Chunk("\nResultaten per game", titleFont));
            ct.AddElement(paragraph);

            // Table: Results per game
            var table = CreateTable(new string[] { "Game", "Unieke spelers", "Resultaat" });

            var gameResultList = statisticsService.GetOrganisationalUnitStatistics(1, 20, organisationalUnit, roleId, fromDate, toDate);
            foreach (var gameResultItem in gameResultList)
            {
                table.AddCell(new iTextSharp.text.Phrase(gameResultItem.Game, rowFont));
                table.AddCell(new iTextSharp.text.Phrase(gameResultItem.NumberOfUsers.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), rowFont));
                var percentage = gameResultItem.AveragePercentage.HasValue ? string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}%", gameResultItem.AveragePercentage) : "?";
                table.AddCell(new iTextSharp.text.Phrase(percentage, rowFont));
            }

            table.CompleteRow();

            ct.AddElement(table);

            paragraph = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(new ITextSharp.Chunk("\nResultaten per kenniscategorie", titleFont));
            ct.AddElement(paragraph);

            // Table: Results per knowledgecategory
            table = CreateTable(new string[] { "Kenniscategorie", "Gemiddeld", "Laagste", "Hoogste", "Standaard deviatie" });

            var knowledgeCategoryResultList = statisticsService.GetGlobalKnowledgeCategoryResultStatistics(
                organisationalUnit,
                roleId,
                fromDate,
                toDate);

            foreach (var knowledgeCategoryResultItem in knowledgeCategoryResultList)
            {
                table.AddCell(new iTextSharp.text.Phrase(knowledgeCategoryResultItem.KnowledgeCategory.Name, rowFont));
                table.AddCell(new iTextSharp.text.Phrase(
                    knowledgeCategoryResultItem.Statistics.Average.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), 
                    rowFont));
                table.AddCell(new iTextSharp.text.Phrase(
                    knowledgeCategoryResultItem.Statistics.Minimum.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), 
                    rowFont));
                table.AddCell(new iTextSharp.text.Phrase(
                    knowledgeCategoryResultItem.Statistics.Maximum.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), 
                    rowFont));
                table.AddCell(new iTextSharp.text.Phrase(
                    knowledgeCategoryResultItem.Statistics.StDev.HasValue ? knowledgeCategoryResultItem.Statistics.StDev.Value.ToString(
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) : "?", 
                    rowFont));
            }

            table.CompleteRow();

            ct.AddElement(table);

            // Parse
            ct.Go();

            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
            pdfStamper.FreeTextFlattening = true;

            // Close stamper explicitly, otherwise the pdf gets corrupted (don't wait until the Dispose is called in the using-clause)
            pdfStamper.Close();

            // Always call ToArray, to get all the bytes returned.
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Generally speaking, `PdfStamper` is intended to be used with existing PDFs, not new PDFs. Is there a reason that you're doing it this way? If you switch to the normal `Document` and `PdfWriter` model then tables wrap exactly as you'd expect them. But if for some reason you need to do this you could try what Bruno is talking about here although I've never tried it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13539904/231316

Comment: Oh yes, the EmptyPdf is in fact an A4 pdf with a footer logo, it must be stamped this way.

Comment: Then I'd try the `HasMoreText()` route and if it works, great but if not I'd recommend making the "add logo" part of the second pass since that's really easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

I see you take an existing PDF file (referred to as `"emptyPdfFile"`) add content to that PDF (2 tables) and want to add pages as necessary.  So I assume you actually want to create a PDF from scratch.

In that case it's most likely easier to use PdfWriter and add your tables using `Document.Add()`. Tables will be split and pages will be added automatically when the end of the current page is reached.
A simple example of adding a table with `Document.Add()` can be found here in the [`MyFirstTable`](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=75) example (that's iText code in Java, check [the C# port](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C04) for iTextSharp code).

If you do want to follow the approach of your example code, using `PdfReader`, `PdfStamper` and `ColumnText`:

`ColumnText.Go()` adds content to the defined area until that area is full.  Any remaining content stays in the `ColumnText` object.  So if you want to split the content over multiple areas, you have to loop and call `ColumnText.Go()` until all content is consumed.

Here's an example of the `ColumnText.Go()` looping: [`ColumnTable`](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=91) (Again, you may want to check [the C# port](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C04)).

In that example the tables are layed out in 2 columns on each page, but the approach stays the same for 1 table per page.
Note that `Document.NewPage()` is used in the example to add an extra page.  You'll have to replace this call with `PdfStamper.InsertPage()` in your case.